# How do I use INotifyPropertyChanged to update an array binding?

Tags: wpf

Let's say I have a class:

```
class Foo
{
  public string Bar
  {
    get { ... }
  }

  public string this[int index]
  {
    get { ... }
  }
}
```

I can bind to these two properties using "{Binding Path=Bar}" and "{Binding Path=[x]}". Fine.

Now let's say I want to implement INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public string Bar
  {
    get { ... }
    set
    {
      ...

      if( PropertyChanged != null )
      {
        PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( "Bar" ) );
      }
    }
  }

  public string this[int index]
  {
    get { ... }
    set
    {
      ...

      if( PropertyChanged != null )
      {
        PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( "????" ) );
      }
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

What goes in the part marked ????? (I've tried string.Format("[{0}]", index) and it doesn't work). Is this a bug in WPF, is there an alternative syntax, or is it simply that INotifyPropertyChanged isn't as powerful as normal binding?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to Cameron's suggestion, I've found the correct syntax, which is:

```
Item[]
```

Which updates everything (all index values) bound to that indexed property.

Answer (score 6):

Avoiding strings in your code, you can use the constant `Binding.IndexerName`, which is actually `"Item[]"`

```
new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Binding.IndexerName)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( "Item[]" ) )
```

for all indexes and

```
PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( "Item[" + index + "]" ) )
```

for a single item

greetings, jerod

Comment: Did you try this? PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[" + key + "]") does not work for me with a string key.

Comment: Nor for me with an integer :(

Comment: PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[" + key + "]") does not work for me either, although I sure would like it to!

Answer (score 3):

Don't know for sure if this'll work, but reflector shows that the get and set methods for an indexed property are called get_Item and set_Item. Perhaps you could try Item and see if that works.